# C# p/invoke, Reading data from an Owner Drawn List Box

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, ownerdrawn

I have an Owner Drawn List Box in an external application (*America Online*) that I need to get data out of for building a component to assist people with its usability. (the utility will be making access of certain things more simple, etc).

### Notice

My knowledge of C++ is **very poor**. I am a C# programmer.

I have the `hWnd` to the List Box in question, but it appears to be owner drawn. Using `LB_GETTEXT` returns bad data, I just get junk (it renders in my debugger as a bunch of chinese characters) and going through `LB_GETITEMDATA` returns much the same.

I believe this is because the owner drawn list box has graphics on it. Doing **a lot** of digging, I have discovered others in the past with this problem. I have unearthed the following code that is supposed to remedy this issue. However it does not. The code is posted below, and the issues beneath it.

```
void GetListItemData( HWND hListWnd, long index, char *outputResult )
{
    int result;
    DWORD processID;
    HANDLE hProcess;
    char *itemData;
    char sDataRead[5];
    DWORD bytes;
    DWORD lListItemHold, lListItemDataHold;
    *outputResult=0;

    if( hListWnd )
    {
        GetWindowThreadProcessId( hListWnd, &processID );

        hProcess=OpenProcess( 0x10|0xf0000|PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, processID );

        if( hProcess )
        {
            lListItemHold=(DWORD)SendMessage( hListWnd, LB_GETITEMDATA, index-1, 0 );
            lListItemHold=lListItemHold+24;

            result=ReadProcessMemory( hProcess, (void *)lListItemHold, &sDataRead, 4, &bytes );
            if( !result )
            {
                RaiseWinErr();
            }

            memcpy( &lListItemDataHold, &sDataRead, 4 );
            lListItemDataHold=lListItemDataHold+6;

            ReadProcessMemory( hProcess, (void *)lListItemDataHold, outputResult, 16, &bytes );

            CloseHandle( hProcess );
        }
    }
}
```

My understanding, limited as it is, is that `lListItemHold=lListItemHold+24` tries to account for whatever 'structure' is in the ListBox and pass through the first 24 bytes of it, and return what remains. However this does not seem to be working for me.

Can anyone shed some light on things I could try? I know I am grasping at straws as it is. I am coding this in C#, so this function is used using `p/invoke` such as follows;

```
    [DllImport("GetListItemData.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    internal static extern void RetrieveListItem(
        System.IntPtr hWnd,
        System.Int32 index,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]byte[] buffer
    );

    [DllImport("GetListItemData.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    internal static extern void RetrieveListItem(
        System.IntPtr hWnd,
        System.Int32 index,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]System.Text.StringBuilder buffer
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two blog posts on the topic

http://taylorza.blogspot.com/2009/08/archive-hacking-my-way-across-process.html
http://taylorza.blogspot.com/2010/06/crossing-process-boundary-with-net.html

These however are for a ListView control, but you might want to take a look at the code. The second post is using P/Invoke to achieve this in .NET.

1- Why are you adding 24 to lListItemHold?

2- Are you sure lListItemhold is a pointer to a string, it might be some internal structure of the application.

Comment: I didn't write the original code. I am not sure why the +24 has to be added, I just know that it doesn't work without it. I've actually gotten the C++ code to run, but it crashes some machines - so I know I am on the right track.

Comment: If I wanted to add the +24 to the p/invoke version (the second link), which variable would I do that to? I'm not sure what corrolates to what, here - where do I add the +24 and the +6 as seen in my C# code to get the same result? Any idea?

Comment: Yeah... The second one looks good, but it just isn't getting the data. I need to be able to add in the buffering like the C++ version. That +24 and +6 is used to offset the result so it gets a string, instead of junk.

Comment: @Stacey, America Online what is that? Is there somewhere I could get a hold of it and to take a look at it? I am not in or from the US so I do not know the application.

Comment: You can, but you don't want to, trust me. If it weren't a mandatory part of my specific clients application I wouldn't touch it. But you can get it at http://daol.aol.com/software/aoldesktop96/ - be sure to read the setup to make sure it doesn't try to do any 'defaults' to your programs.

Comment: If you decide to download it, let me know, and I will get with you and show you more closely what I am doing.